# How come PopupWindow.OnDismissListener is not called when using Robolectric?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-popupwindow

I have a problem. I want to write a test for code that relies on execution of the PopupWindow.OnDismissListener.onDismiss() method. However, it never seems to be called. Am I doing something wrong?

Sample code:

```
View content = new View(Robolectric.application);
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(content, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            Assert.fail();
        }
});
View anchor = new View(Robolectric.application);
popup.showAsDropDown(anchor);
popup.dismiss();
```

The above test never fails! I have tried adding a small sleep after, in case there were some timing issues.
I have looked at the generated code for the PopupWindow.class, but couldn't find anything there either.

Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't catch anything. Besides, wouldn't any exceptions turn up when you run the code anyway?

Comment: hmm it seems that it is an window manager issue,  instead of calling directly two last statements call anchor.post(r) where r is a Runnable that calls those two statements in run() method, both anchor and popup needs to be final in order to do that

Comment: did you call anchor.post() ?

Comment: yes, both final and anchor.post()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the listener isn't called is because the ShadowPopupWindow from Robolectric overrides the default implementation and simply doesn't call it.

Code from [source](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/e5c2ded1b953fd95d59ff402ff1de9fdb2a83847/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowPopupWindow.java#L118-L122):

```
  public void dismiss() {
    if (context != null) {
      getWindowManager().removeView(containerView);
    }
    showing = false;
  }
```

Depending on what it is you need to test, there may be a valid workaround (your sample code above pretty much just tests the internals of PopupWindow, which I am guessing is not what you are actually looking to achieve). You could also make your own [custom shadow](http://robolectric.org/custom-shadows/), extending this one, where you choose to do a different behaviour.

Comment: excellent, thank you! You're right, the above code is just a sample to make it more clear what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer using dialog boxes instead. To build an AlertDialog, use something like below from the Developers page:

```
/ 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor 
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics 
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create() 
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I can't change the type though, and I need to know if this is a bug, if there is a workaround or if I'm doing anything wrong...